# Bootstrap model not working with command link in VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, bootstrap

## VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="acccheck" docType="HTML-5.0" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <style type= "text/css">

    </style>
   </head>
     <body>
      <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
                  <div class="container-fluid">
                     <div class="panel panel-default">
                       <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-default class</div>
                         <div class="panel-body">  
                               <table class="table table-hover">
                                    <thead>
                                       <tr>
                                          <th>Name</th>
                                       </tr>
                                    </thead>  
                                    <apex:repeat value="{!acc}" var="c">
                                    <tbody>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td> 
                                              <apex:commandLink action="{!details}" styleClass="btn btn-link" value="{!c.name}" html-data-toggle="modal" html-data-target="#display" >
                                                  <apex:param value="{!c.id}" name="offname"/>
                                              </apex:commandlink>
                                          </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                    </apex:repeat>
                               </table>
                           </div> 
                         </div>



                         <div class="modal fade" id="display" role="dialog">
                           <div class="modal-dialog">
                              <div class="modal-content">
                                 <div class="model-header"> hello</div>
                                   <div class="model-body">
                                   <apex:repeat value="{!acc1}" var="a">
                                     <apex:outputField value="{!a.name}"/>
                                   </apex:repeat>
                                   </div>
                                  <div class="model-footer">
                                      This is Footer
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                   </div>
      </apex:pageblock> 
    </apex:form>
   </body>
  </html>
</apex:page>
```

## Class

```
public class acccheck {
    public list<account> acc{get;set;}
    public list<account> acc1{get;set;}

    public acccheck(){
        acc=[select id,name from account];
    }

    public void details(){
        string done=apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('offname');
        acc1=[select id,name from account where id=:done ];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are opening the modal popup immediately. Instead, you have to wait till the action callback happened. You can use a `<apex:actionFunction` to do the action call and from the `oncomplete` event open the modal dialog through jQuery. So the modal dialog is updated with data before opening. I have also wrapped the modal dialog inside a `<apex:outputPanel` so that it can be rerendered from `<apex:actionFunction`. I tried to modify your code and I can see the data in the popup.

```
<apex:page controller="acccheck" docType="HTML-5.0" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <style type= "text/css">

            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function openModal(){
                    $('#display').modal({
                        keyboard: true
                    })                    
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <apex:form >
                <apex:outputText value="{!acc1}" id="opt"></apex:outputText>
                <apex:actionFunction action="{!details}" name="fetchDetails" oncomplete="openModal();" reRender="modalw">
                    <apex:param name="offname" value=""/>
                </apex:actionFunction>
                <apex:pageBlock >
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-default class</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">  
                                <table class="table table-hover">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Name</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>  
                                    <apex:repeat value="{!acc}" var="c">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td> 
                                                    <a class="btn btn-link" onclick="fetchDetails('{!c.id}');" >{!c.name}</a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </apex:repeat>
                                </table>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <apex:outputPanel id="modalw">
                        <div class="modal fade" id="display" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="model-header"> hello</div>
                                    <div class="model-body">
                                        <apex:repeat value="{!acc1}" var="a">
                                            <apex:outputField value="{!a.name}"/>
                                        </apex:repeat>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="model-footer">
                                        This is Footer
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </div>
                </apex:pageblock> 
            </apex:form>
        </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `rerender` attribute in your command Link

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!details}" styleClass="btn btn-link" value="{!c.name}" html-data-toggle="modal" html-data-target="#display" rerender="innerPanel">
      <apex:param value="{!c.id}" name="offname"/>
</apex:commandlink>
```

In your model popup

```
<apex:outputpanel layout="block" id="innerPanel" styleclass="model-body">
            <apex:repeat value="{!acc1}" var="a">
                   <apex:outputField value="{!a.name}"/>
             </apex:repeat>
</apex:outputpanel>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54594/discussion-on-answer-by-tushar-sharma-bootstrap-model-not-working-with-command-l).

Comment: @SarojBera this code is also working I don't think we need extra JavaScript code here.